# Mapping UML Class Diagram to Python Code

Tags: uml

I've been asked to document a piece of code using UML diagrams. The code models a situation like the following: a driver can be assigned to one or more routes. Each route has an upstream and a downstream direction. For each route the driver can drive in the upstream direction and/or in the downstream direction.

A simplified pseudo-code is for the Driver class is the following:

```
class Driver:

  HashMap<Route, Direction> upstream;
  HashMap<Route, Direction> downstream;
  HashMap<Route, Direction> assignedTo;
```

where the assignedTo map is actually a property returning a hashmap composed of the routes where the driver is assigned to both the upstream and downstream directions (think of it as a view on the other two hashmaps)

So far I've come up the the following UML representation.

```
-----------                            ---------
| CLASS   | (assignedTo)               | CLASS |
| DRIVER  |----------------------------| ROUTE |
----------- *   |                    * ---------
                |
            -------------
            | CLASS     |
            | DIRECTION |
            -------------
              ^        ^
              |        |
      ------------    --------------    
      | CLASS    |    | CLASS      |
      | UPSTREAM |    | DOWNSTREAM |
      ------------    --------------
```

However, I'm a little puzzled by the fact that in the UML I;m using inheritance while the code uses no inheritance. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a little but this is another sample of mine. I am not sure if I understand the shown pseudo-code correctly, but the case when assigned to both directions, it could be a problem. In my personal opinion, my sample diagram would be easier for implementation too.

[image]

Regarding the inheritance, the answer would be different what this UML is for.. to represent how to implement or to explain the concepts. If the latter, there would be no problem using inheritance.